# Which version of Java should I use for Clojure (performance)?

Tags: clojure, jvm

In order to get the most performance, should I use the latest Java, i.e. Java 8 for Clojure 1.6 development?

Will Java 8 improves JVM performance over Java 7?

Comment: I think the performance difference will not be significant. Clojure only requires Java 1.6 or above: [Official Getting Stared](http://clojure.org/getting_started)

Comment: Clojure doesn't currently take advantage of `invokedynamic`, so it won't benefit as much as languages that do. Will Java 1.8 have any performance benefit for you at all? We have no possible way of telling that without benchmarking it on **your** code. In general, though, newer JVMs are more likely to perform well than old ones regardless of your language of choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java updates generally optimize and improve performance on the most common operations - allocation, synchronization, virtual calls, etc. All of those are entirely applicable to Clojure code.

Anecdotally, Java 8 seems about 10% faster than Java 7 for me on typical Clojure programs.

My general recommendation is to use the newest stable Java version for Clojure applications.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Java generally are faster than old versions. I would expect Java 8 to be at least the same, if not a little faster for Clojure code.

Java 8 is faster than Java 6 and Java 7 in this benchmark: http://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2014/03/20/HowMuchFasterIsJava8.html

Comment: the question is specifically about clojure  ;-)